# Meteor Template, where does it come from?

Tags: meteor

I have been studying the todos example for Meteor.

http://www.meteor.com/examples/todos

I vaguely understand how to use Template from the example.  But where is this declared?  I've tried looking at the packages that Meteor uses to find it.  I've also searched Google, but there are too many templating systems.

Where is the best place to learn about Template and how it is used with Meteor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlebars is the only templating system right now. Templates are explained throughly in http://docs.meteor.com/#templates.

> Today, the only templating system that has been packaged for Meteor is
>   Handlebars.

Comment: Thanks, I was mainly wondering about the global Template object.  It seems from the doc that this is generated by Meteor and just serves a namespace of sorts?

Comment: BTW, I was looking to Handlebars to explain the Template, but didn't find it there.

Comment: The route template is in: app/lib/app.html.in but this may change in the future.

See the answer by @debergalis for how to use the templating

Comment: Meteor now supports additional Templating systems. See TomUnite's link  in this answer for details.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the templating Smart Package in `packages/templating`.  It defines the `Template` global.

Then, it scans all the `.html` files in your project.  For each `<template>` tag, it compiles the body of the template into a function that returns HTML and stores that function as a property on Template.  Later, your JS code will attach helper functions as properties of the Template function (like `Template.my_template.my_helper`).

Currently, every template element is interpreted as Handlebars.  That will change.